# Regex to find specific number using Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex to find the maxtimeout value (40 in the following) in the RequestReadTimeout directive in Apache config. file, for example :

```
RequestReadTimeout header=XXX-40,MinRate=XXX body=XXX
RequestReadTimeout header=40 body=XXX
```

PS : XXX refer to a decimal digit

I used this :

```
str="RequestReadTimeout header=10-40,MinRate=10 body=10"
re.search(r'header=\d+[-\d+]*', str).group()
'header=10-40'
```

But I need a regex to get only the maxtimeout value (40 in this example) in one row (without using other function like spit("-")[1] ...etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd *group* the part you wanted to extract:

```
re.search(r'header=(?:\d*-)?(\d+)', inputstr).group(1)
```

The `(...)` marks a group, and positional groups like that are numbered starting at 1.

I altered your expression a little to only capture the number after an optional non-capturing group containing digits and a dash, to match both patterns you are looking for. The `(?:...)` is a *non-capturing* group; it doesn't store the matched text in a group, but does let you use the `?` quantifier on the group to mark it optional.

[Pythex demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=header%3D%28%3F%3A%5Cd%2a-%29%3F%28%5Cd%2B%29&test_string=RequestReadTimeout%20header%3D1234-40%2CMinRate%3DXXX%20body%3DXXX%0ARequestReadTimeout%20header%3D40%20body%3DXXX%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Python session:

```
>>> import re
>>> for inputstr in ('RequestReadTimeout header=1234-40,MinRate=XXX body=XXX', 'RequestReadTimeout header=40 body=XXX'):
...     print re.search(r'header=(?:\d*-)?(\d+)', inputstr).group(1)
... 
40
40
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the following `regex`:

`'RequestReadTimeout\sheader=(?:\d+)?-?(\d+).*'`

The first captured group `\1` is what you want

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/cD6hY0

Comment: Works for your nice solution !